# akka actors rebalancing among routers

Tags: java, scala, akka, actor, akka-cluster

How to rebalance number of actors among multiple routers. Lets say router1 has 20 actors, router2 has 15 actors. If i want to create a router3 is there a possibility if grabbing n number of actors from router1 and m number of actors from router2.

I know this can be achieved with giving poisonPill to actors and bring new actors to new router. But what is the better approach?

Comment: Since the actors are all running on the same thread pool I'm not sure how adding more actors helps or hurts you in this example. Actors aren't threads and I don't think you need to manage them this way.